# for loop inside for loop takes too long to run

Tags: python-3.x

this is the code its taking too long to run i want to increment the number of visits everytime the name of the driver is repeated

```
df['visites']=1
for i in range(len(df['CHAUFFEUR'])-1):
    for j in range (i,len(df['CHAUFFEUR'])-1):
        if df['CHAUFFEUR'][j] == df['CHAUFFEUR'][i]:
            df['visites'][i]+=1
```

Comment: df['visites']=1
for i in range(len(df['CHAUFFEUR'])-1):
    for j in range (i,len(df['CHAUFFEUR'])-1):
        if df['CHAUFFEUR'][j] == df['CHAUFFEUR'][i]:
            df['visites'][i]+=1

Comment: Do you want to count the appearances (-1) of a driver in ```df['CHAUFFEUR']```?

Comment: yes and i want to put that result as a column in my dataframe

Comment: Are you sure your code gives the wanted result?

Comment: in df['visites'] i want the increment it every time the value of df['CHAUFFEUR'] is repeated for example :                                                                                                                   mouna 1                                                                                                                                   shimon 1                                                                                                                            mouna 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution where you 'remember' who you saw already and skip:

```py
chauffeur = df['CHAUFFEUR']
# Save length in advance (it is used a few times)
length = len(chauffeur)

# Fill visits dictionary with default values for each chauffeur
visits = {}
for c in chauffeur:
    visits[c] = 0

for i in range(length):
    # If we saw this chauffeur, skip
    if visits[chauffeur[i]]:
        continue
    for j in range(i, length):
        if chauffeur[j] == chauffeur[i]:
            visits[chauffeur[i]] += 1
            df['visites'][j] = visits[chauffeur[i]]
```